# onNavigationItemSelected in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to update my UI based on the ongoing Selected Item from the `BottomNavigationView`. The problem is that the item ID will be changed after the whole method inside the listener is executed, and method `getSelectedItemId()` will refer to the item that was selected before when I called it inside `updateUI()` method.

How I can work around this?

Here is the code:

```
        mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_baby:
                case R.id.navigation_you:
                case R.id.navigation_partner: {
                    updateUI();
                    return true;
                }
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Update Method:

The value of `mBottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()` refer to the previous selection

```
private void updateUI() { 
    mBagListAdapter.setList(mPregnancyLab.getBagList(mBottomNavigationView.getSelectedItemId()));
    mBagListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: How will `ID` change? Please add more details to the question...

Comment: @Vishnu Please check now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
    mBottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
           
         mBagListAdapter.setList(mPregnancyLab.getBagList(item.getItemId()));
         BagListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Hope this helps. Feel free to ask for clarifications...